# How to convert Class<T>#cast method from Java to Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I want to convert the following code from Java:

```
Object from = ...
Class<T> toClass = ...

T result = toClass.cast(from);
```

to Kotlin:

```
Any? from = ...
KClass<T> toClass = ...

T result = // toClass.cast(from) - how to convert this line to Kotlin?
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the `Class<T>` instance with the `java` property

This should work: `toClass.java.cast(from)`

Answer (score 0):

for any java to Kotlin converter, use the online converter provided on the site.

http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Longer%20examples/Maze/Maze.kt